Can't send json reponse in requests mock
I'm looking for a way to test a function called fetch_options that basically renders a returned JSONResponse from an internal API. My approach to this test is to mock requests because the internal API is located in another app which has already tested in a different test suite.
I've got a gut feeling that the function is properly patched with the mock but for some reason my render call can't get the response data, I might be wrong about this though.
planner/views/meals.py
def fetch_options(request, meal, field):
    if field == "ingredients":
        index = 1
    else:
        index = 0

    try:
        response = requests.get("log/api/send_" + field) #Trying to mock requests here, request fetches from /log/views/api.py
    except ConnectionError:
        requests.raise_from_exception()
    else:
        return render(request, {"meal": meal, "options": list(response)[index]}) # throws list index out range in tests

/log/views/api.py
def send_data(request, option):
    match option:
        case "ingredients":
            data = Log.objects.first().recipe_ingredients
        case "areas":
            data = Log.objects.first().recipe_area
        case "categories":
            data = Log.objects.first().recipe_categories
        case "activities":
            data = Log.objects.first().activities
    response = JsonResponse(data, status=200, safe=False)
    return response

planner/tests/test_meals_view.py
from unittest import MagicMock, patch

@patch("planner.views.meals.requests")
def test_fetch_options(self, mock_requests):
    mock_response = MagicMock()
    mock_response.status_code = 200
    mock_response.json_data = [{"id": "357", "strIngredient": "Orange"}]
    mock_requests.get.return_value = mock_response
    self.assertContains(
        fetch_options("request", "breakfast", "ingredients"), status_code=200
    )

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong please?

Hi Wave! Has this been solved? Do you still need help?

Hey @ChukwujiobiCanon! Yeah, I your answer showed me some of the things I was doing wrong. Fixed the problem, posted the answer and gave you some credits but I forgot to mark it as the most useful answer. Thanks again for your help \m/

Chukwujiobi Canon's answer gave me crucial pointers to solve the problem. They were more errors in the code I made out of being distracted (I've been working on this project for a while now)
planner/views/meals.py
def fetch_options(request, meal, field):
    try:
        response = requests.get("log/api/send_" + field)
    except ConnectionError:
        requests.raise_from_exception()
    else:
        data = response.json()
        return render(
            request,
            "planner/edit_meal.html",
            {"meal": meal, "options": data},
        )

planner/tests/test_meals_view.py
@patch("planner.views.meals.requests")
    def test_fetch_options(self, mock_requests):
        mock_response = MagicMock()
        mock_response.status_code = 200
        mock_response.json.return_value = ["Orange", "Pineapple", "Watermelon"]
        mock_requests.get.return_value = mock_response
        self.assertContains(
            fetch_options("request", "breakfast", "ingredients"),
            "Orange",
            status_code=200,
        )

log/views/api.py remains the same

1. You are creating a list containing one element —response [requests-docs]— at list(response). If field == "ingredients", index == 1. See the error now? When indexing a list containing one element at index 1, an IndexError exception is raised.
2. The helper function render() [django-docs] does not take the function signature you used:
render(request, {"meal": meal, "options": list(response)[index]})
The correct signature would be:
render(request, template_name, •••Rest of parameters•••)

My recommendation would be:
1. Read the Response from requests.get() first and extract the data as JSON or Text.
response.json()
# OR
response.text
2. Consider constructing and returning a Django HttpResponse directly instead of using render() which will result in HTML rendering with the Context data passed to render(). I’m suggesting this because I realized that you don’t need the HTML rendering since all you are checking for is status_code in:
self.assertContains(
    fetch_options("request", "breakfast", "ingredients"), status_code=200
)

Thanks a lot! Your answer made me realize I wasn't paying attention at how data was actually organized in the data base plus other missing bits of code that obviously were not helping to the whole problem at all. Just upvoted your answer because it contributed to finding the solution and I'll post my code based on it so others won't get misled
